# jQuery and WebGL - moving a div on a mouse move

Tags: jquery, html, webgl

So, what's the problem? I've got a div with "position:absolute" property. Now - I was wondering - can I move this div with jQuery (or simple javascript), each time when the mouse moves? And it's about a constant and increasing move, only on the X axis. So - imagine a left and right side of the browser window. When - for example - mouse cursor is on the left half - this div slowly moves right all the time; and also when cursor gets closer and closer to the left edge - speed of a div is increased a bit. I'm trying to learn WebGL on Three.js engine. Let me show you an example:

look here - http://hadyk.pl/webgl/ (probably doesn't work in IE)

Look at the way stars are moving, when you move the cursor - I want to achieve the same with the background div.

Thanks

EDIT: Ok, I got it working. Look at upgraded link. Code:

Script:

`$('#background').css( {backgroundPosition: "0px bottom"} )`

```
function moveRight() { 
                $('#background').stop().animate({right:  "1500px"},
                {duration:80000});
}
function moveLeft() { 
                $('#background').stop().animate({right:  "-1500px"},
                {duration:80000});
}
function onStop() {
                $('#background').stop();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="left" onMouseOver="moveLeft()" onMouseOut="onStop()"></div>
<div id="right" onMouseOver="moveRight()" onMouseOut="onStop()"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
            background: #000 url(images/moon.png) no-repeat;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            width:411px;
            height:404px;
            z-index:-2;
}
#left {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
            width:30%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:99
}
#right {
            position:absolute;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            width:30%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:99
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an error here:

```
function moveBackground() {
    $('#background').css({'right':(parseInt($('#background').css('right')) + (e.pageX*0.001))+'px'});
window.setTimeout(moveBackground(), 50);
}
```

You forgot the `e` in the function parameter:

```
function moveBackground(e) {
    $('#background').css({'right':(parseInt($('#background').css('right')) + (e.pageX*0.001))+'px'});
window.setTimeout(moveBackground(), 50);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've corrected it - and made something like that (but it's not working): $('canvas').mousemove(function moveBackground(e) {
  if (e.pageX > (window.innerWidth / 2)) {
  $('#background').css({'right':(parseInt($('#background').css('right')) + (e.pageX*0.0008))+'px'});
  }
  if (e.pageX < (window.innerWidth / 2)) {
  $('#background').css({'right':(parseInt($('#background').css('right')) - (e.pageX*0.0008))+'px'});
  }
 });

Comment: Delete `moveBackground` in your function deceleration. It should be `mousemove(function(e) {`. Also, your second `if` statement is really redundant. Replace it with an `else` clause.

Comment: Ok, I came with different approach. I've discovered the plugin - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect . Please look again at my link in the first post. Now it works much better - but there are still two problems: 1. Why is it so slow in Firefox and Chrome? 2. I can't make it work on two sides - it moves only left. What am I missing ? Is the condition wrong - `if (mouseX > (window.innerWidth / 2)) {` ?

Comment: You are using *very* inefficient code. You are loading/unloading functions every time the user moves their mouse. Try to get rid of that code.